# Hypotheses on integrator that Riemann-Stieltjes integrable function on $[0,1]$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\alpha$ be nondecreasing on $[0,1]$. Then Riemann-Stieltjes integrable function is well defined with respect to the integrator $\alpha$.

My questions are as follows:

> (1) Let $f$ be Riemann-Stieltjes integrable on $[0,1]$ with respect to $\alpha$. Is $f$ Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$ with respect to the measure induced by $\alpha$?
>
> (2) Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,1]$.  Is $f$ Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$ with respect to the measure induced by $\alpha$?
>
> (3) If not, what additional assumptions on  $\alpha$ do we need  for guaranteeing Lebesgue integrability of $f$?  For example, $\alpha$ is right-continuous or continuous on $[0,1]$.

[EDIT] I found a paper related to my question 
[https://www.jstor.org/stable/2323739?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents]

It seems that (1) is true. Am I right?

I would be grateful if you give any comment for my question.

Comment: Did you check the wikipedia page of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral, for example? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration

Comment: @Botond Yes I did. I’d like to know if the monotonicity of the integrator $\alpha$ is sufficient to guaranteeing (1) is true. What is the purpose for giving the right continuity of $\alpha$?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with the measure theory, but I think we need it because of the Borel measure needs half-open sets.

Comment: I think one should check, if $\alpha$ induces a measure if it is not right continuous. The proof I have seen uses the right continuity to show $\sigma$-additivity and regularity in terms of compact approximation of the measure.

Comment: @John  I think PMA by Rudin is the reference for it.